# JAVAFX_HOME path doesn't work

Tags: java, environment-variables, javafx

I have installed JavaFX SDK on my machine, and set the JAVAFX_HOME environmental variable to the root directory of the SDK but when I try to echo it on the commandline, I only get back what I wrote after echo:

C:\Java\workspace-ecmc\CMX\CmxDesigner>echo %JAVAFX_HOME%

%JAVAFX_HOME%

I acted the same with JAVA_HOME but it works properly.

Comment: I will almost say that you make a type mistake..

Comment: have you tried to close every cmd, open a new one (after the declaration of the variable) and echo your new environment variable? Also, check that your environment variable is in the System section

Comment: Why do you need a JAVAFX_HOME environment variable?  What uses this environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, set the environment variable as
`JAVAFX_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK`.

Then assign `PATH` to `%JAVAFX_HOME%\bin;`
and try echo `%JAVAFX_HOME%`. It'll work.